# Constructing a complete affine 3D transformation matrix with homogeneous coordinates.

Tags: matrices

I have been able to scale, rotate, and translate a 2D point represented by a 3x1 matrix as such:

$$P = \left( \array{ x \\ y \\1 } \right)$$

The affine transformation that I apply to $P$ is this one:

$$A = \left( \array{ x_s * \cos(\theta) & y_s * -\sin(\theta) &x_d  \\ 
                     x_s*\sin(\theta) & y_s*\cos(\theta) & y_d \\
                     0 &0 & 1} \right)$$

Where $x_s$ and $y_s$ are for scaling, $\theta$ is for rotating, and $x_d$ and $y_d$ are the translations. This works correctly, but I wish to integrate shearing as well which is:

$$H = \left( \array{ 1 & h_x & 0 \\ 
                     h_y & 1 & 0 \\
                     0 & 0 & 1}  \right)$$

Where $h_x$ and $h_y$ are the values to shear on the x and y.

How can I integrate the shearing element into matrix $A$?

My first thought was to simply add the shearing elements to $\theta$:

$$A = \left( \array{ x_s * \cos(\theta) & y_s * -\sin(\theta + h_x) &x_d  \\ 
                     x_s*\sin(\theta + h_y) & y_s*\cos(\theta) & y_d \\
                     0 &0 & 1} \right)$$

Since the shearing elements are the degrees (or radians) of shearing

Answer (score 1):

You can combine arbitrary affine transformations by multiplying the corresponding matrices. For $3\times 3$ matrices, the formula for computing the product is $$
\begin{eqnarray}
 &\begin{pmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ 
    a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ 
    a_{31} &a_{32} & a_{33}
  \end{pmatrix}
  \cdot
  \begin{pmatrix}
    b_{11} & b_{12} & b_{13} \\ 
    b_{21} & b_{22} & b_{23} \\ 
    b_{31} & b_{32} & b_{33}
  \end{pmatrix} \\
  &= 
  \begin{pmatrix}
     \small{a_{11}b_{11} + a_{12}b_{21} + a_{13}b_{31}} & 
     \small{a_{11}b_{12} + a_{12}b_{22} + a_{13}b_{32}} & 
     \small{a_{11}b_{13} + a_{12}b_{23} + a_{13}b_{33}} \\
     \small{a_{21}b_{11} + a_{22}b_{21} + a_{23}b_{31}} & 
     \small{a_{21}b_{12} + a_{22}b_{22} + a_{23}b_{32}} & 
     \small{a_{21}b_{13} + a_{22}b_{23} + a_{23}b_{33}} \\
     \small{a_{31}b_{11} + a_{32}b_{21} + a_{33}b_{31}} & 
     \small{a_{31}b_{12} + a_{32}b_{22} + a_{33}b_{32}} & 
     \small{a_{31}b_{13} + a_{32}b_{23} + a_{33}b_{33}}
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

For more details see [matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication)